# How to fail a Python CI GitHub Action job if mypy returns errors?

Tags: python, github-actions, mypy

I have my GitHub action that has runs-on set to `windows-latest` and my `mypy` command.

jobs:
build:

```
runs-on: windows-latest

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}
- name: Set up Python 3.x
  uses: actions/setup-python@v2
  with:
    python-version: '3.8'
- name: Install dependencies
  run: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install mypy
    pip install -r requirements.txt
- name: Lint with mypy
  run: |
    Get-ChildItem . -Filter "*.py" -Recurse | foreach {mypy $_.FullName `
        --show-error-codes `
        --raise-exceptions
    }
```

I have errors in the GitHub console for the action run, but it doesn't cause the job to fail. How can I make the job fail on `mypy` errors?

The `mypy` documentation doesn't mention anything about specifying failure on errors, or specifying error return codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fail the job or step then you need to return a non 0 exit code.
See here: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/creating-actions/setting-exit-codes-for-actions

I'm not familiar with what mypy is doing in your example, but if you want it to fail the step based on some output, then you should probably save the output to a variable, check it for what you are expecting as a 'failure' and then 'exit 1' so that returns to github actions which will subsequently fail that step.